# iphone 5S slow motion is gone when exporting a video

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to let the user of my app pick a video from his camera roll and play it,
So I created my own custom picker (need custom UI) to choose the video and when the user pick a video I use `AVAssetExportSession` to export the video's asset to mp4 file.

If you didn't knew the new iPhone 5S has an option to apply slow motion on a video.
However when I export a video with slow motion, the slow motion is gone.

I suspect there is some extra data on the video asset that represent the slow motion part and store information of witch part of the video should be play in lower FPS.

I had a similar issue before with photos, for example if you edit a photo with one of the native iOS filters or crop, and than load the photo using AVAsset to an image view, you will see the original photo (without the filters or crop).
Only after examining the `ALAssetRepresentation`  metadata "AdjustmentXMP" key, and applying `CIFilter`'s accordingly, you will get the edited image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The video is not 'recorded in slow-mo' it's recorded in 60 frames per second, and then there is an option to play back in 30 frames per second, creating the effect of slow motion. Try setting the frame-rate on your playback after accessing the asset to 30.

Comment: how can I know which part of the asset is in slow mo? and how can I set only this part to run at 30 FPS? and i'm sure apple uses some kind of curve from 60 to 30 and back to 60..

Comment: The entire video asset is in 60fps. Using the controls in Apple's native Photos.app to slow down only certain sections of the video does not modify the actual asset (video file). This information may be stored somewhere in the metadata (I'm not sure off-hand and I'm not on my Mac at the moment to investigate in code) but you would need to handle changing that during the plackback yourself. You may want to create your own controls for users to set the slow motion area.

Comment: what your saying is to create the slow motion effect by myself, sure it's possible, but I'm looking for a way to apply the slow mo without processing buffers. I have another situation where I just need to export the video file to a remote server, so I just want to apply the slow mo, without playback, just export the file.

Comment: Facing the same issue. It reproduces moreover on iPhone 6/6+. Any updates?

Comment: @Eyal could you please find some time to answer?

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan sorry but I didnt find any good solutions for this issue

Comment: @Eyal thanks for the answer.   
You may be interested in next info - I've tried Instagram application - everything works fine - app exports video with slow motion. Tested on iPhone 6, so it is possible - you may check. 
Still wondering how they did it at Instagram.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue with the use of new iOS 8 **Photos** framework.